# Реальный порядок столбиков в DataGrid

Tags: avalonia

При перемещении столбика порядок обхода остается прежним , тоесть foreach (var ff1 in list1.Columns) делает обход без учета нового положения столбиков . Есть ли другой способ или надо самому сортировать ?

Comment: дать ему уникальный `Id` ?

Comment: Да вроде у него есть уникальный ид это DisplayIndex вот только foreach делается не по DisplayIndex а по первоначальному положению столбиков и не меняется .

Comment: может тут что найдете https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74923125/how-to-set-the-default-user-column-sort-in-avalonias-datagrid